# Command line anti virus scanner for offline usage

Tags: command-line, antivirus

I want a good anti virus software that should have following requirements:

- Be able to scan offline. So no upload to cloud etc
- Be able to be started via command line. Example: "C:\AV\AwesomeAv.exe -file='C:\potentialVirus.zip'"
- No need to install a dedicated AV thats runs in the background with real time scan etc.
- Can run on Windows 10

At first I thought about the command line scanner tool from **HitmanPro** but I noticed that this scanner can't be used offline.

I know about **emsisoft** and **Adaware** but are there other alternatives for me? The scanner can cost money or can be free to use

Answer (score 2):

You can check [ClamAV](https://www.clamav.net/) which is opensource, run on batches, can work offline.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Defender (Built into Windows)

Emsisoft emergency kit
https://www.emsisoft.com/en/home/emergency-kit/

AdwCleaner
https://www.malwarebytes.com/adwcleaner

Stinger (Use --ePO to stop Silent install of RealProtect)
https://www.mcafee.com/en-us/consumer-corporate/mcafee-labs/free-tools/stinger.html

TDSSKiller
https://support.kaspersky.com/common/disinfection/5350

KVRT
https://www.kaspersky.com/downloads/free-virus-removal-tool

ClamwinAV
https://clamwin.com/download/

MSRT
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/intelligence/safety-scanner-download?view=o365-worldwide

I've tested all the above scanners..
They are in a particular order.. 1st is Best in my opinion..
Based on my Preferences.. And Experiences..

List of Various Scanners with CMD options: Kinda Interesting:
https://akeles.jira.com/wiki/spaces/ACJ/pages/56098818/Compatible+Antivirus+Command+Line+Scanners

Hope it helps :)

Comment: The site is called recommendations, not Google Search.  The idea is to give it a review

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/66506)

Comment: My Answer Provides Enough detail to be a helpful answer to the question with a name and link for convenience.. Regarding your google search remark. And even if the links become redundant people can search the name or see the reference in most links.. like to kaspersky for KVRT.. I do agree about the review though.. Would take awhile to review all of those though :)